# SSD (SATA) Disk along side RAID with 3 Disks

Tags: ssd, motherboard, raid, sata

I have the P6T7 WS motherboard (https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P6T7_WS_SuperComputer/) and wanted to install 4x 4TB drives as a RAID 10 on the ICH10R Serial ATA connectors (6 times) ,

I have also a marvell SAS controller with two SAS connectors on board.

Where should I then add my boot SSD disk (SATA) ?

- also to the 5/6 connector on the ICH10R Serial ATA connectors , is this possible since all 6 SATA connectors run in RAID mode?
- or can I plug it to one of the two SAS connectors?

I tried connecting the SSD to the SAS connectors which did not recognize the drive, so far...

How can I use the SSD with this configuration?

Answer (score 2):

Have you RTFM'd?

https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P6T7_WS_SuperComputer/HelpDesk_Manual/

On page 4-46 it states that the ICH10R only supports 4 disks in RAID mode -

> The utility supports maximum four hard disk drives for RAID configuration

On page 4-50 it states that the SAS controller only supports 2 SAS disks

> 1. Install two internal SAS hard disk drives to the SAS connectors labelled **SAS1/2**

Comment: Thanks for beeing polite: Of course I have the FM on my desk, and I read it:  So is it possible to have the SSD at the 5th port, and the other 4 drives in RAID mode?. I assume that works

Comment: Have you tried it? The way I read it is that it wouldn't. It states all 6 ports will be RAID mode if the controller is in RAID mode, it also states that only 4 ports can work in RAID mode. The 2 seem mutually exclusive unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, folks, i tried it, and this setup worked:

2 320gb SATA HDs in Raid 0/1/5/10 (Intel Matrix Storage Manager (the newer name for this is Intel Rapid Storage Technique)
=> this is a BIOS RAID! (CPU is still used!)

with an additional SSD on the third connector of the
Intel ICH10R Serial ATA connectors on NON-RAID mode

So it is no problem to attach non-raid SATA disks additionally :-)